# Entity Framework Core - Foreign Key is NULL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have User and Customer table. User table has a PK of Username and is a FK in Customer table.
I wanted to Add the Customer and User input details into the database with User's Username (Primary Key) being a Foreign Key in Customer Table

Having trouble as to why Username(FK) in Customer table is null

**User:**

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Customer:**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

**DBContext:**

```
class StoreContext : DbContext
{
    readonly string connectionString = @"Data source=...;Integrated security=true;Initial Catalog=dbPizzaOrderingV1";

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        
    }

}
```

**ManageCustomer:**

```
class ManageCustomer
{
    StoreContext context;
    public ManageCustomer()
    {
        context = new StoreContext();
    }
    public bool AddUser(User user)
    {
        context.Users.Add(user);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    public bool AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        context.Customers.Add(customer);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

**Program:**

```
 public void CreateAccount()
 {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    User user = new User();
    Console.WriteLine("Create Account");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Name: ");
    customer.Name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Username: ");
    user.Username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Password: ");
    user.Password = Console.ReadLine();

    manageCustomer.AddUser(user);
    manageCustomer.AddCustomer(customer);
        
    Console.WriteLine("Created Account Successfully!");
 }
```

The User details and Customer details get added to the tables successfully but the username(FK) in customer table is null.
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by properly defining the foreign key of Username

```
 class User
   {
        [Key]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer{ get; set; }
   }

 class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Username))]
        public virtual User User { get; set; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `public string UserId { get; set; }` to Customer class. And the `User` property has to be `virtual`.

Documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships

Answer (score 0):

Fix the classes

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

     public string Username { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserName))]
    [InverseProperty("Customers")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Customer.User))]
    public virtual ICollection Customers {get; set;}
}
```

and code

```
//customer.UserName=user.UserName;
customer.User =user;  
 manageCustomer.AddCustomer(customer);
```

or you can try this too

```
 manageUser.AddUser(user);
customer.UserName=user.UserName;
 manageCustomer.AddCustomer(customer);
```

IMHO you have to add integer Id as a key to User table. Without this User table looks very radiculous and EF is confused. You will not be able to change Username easily since it is a primary key. And maybe you will have to add some fluent APIs as well

Comment: It only created another column of Username in Customer table which is not the FK. The FK is still null.

Comment: You have to post your full dbcontext including ManageCustomer.  It is hard to understand what is your problem and  what is FK ?

Comment: I just updated my post. I wanted to take in and Add the Customer input details and User input details into the database with User's Username (Primary Key) being a Foreign Key in Customer Table

Comment: You have to update the classes and after this to migrate  them to database. ONLY after this you can try again.

Comment: Tried migrating but an error was thrown at  context.Users.Add(user); in ManageCustomer Class for 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: I am sorry but what ManageCustomer has to do with migration? They are completely different classes

Comment: I did it! I added public virtual Customer Customer{ get; set; } at User class and [ForeignKey(nameof(Username))] public virtual User User { get; set; } at Customer class. Now they have a 1 to 1 relationship and the Foreign Key (Username) properly defined! Thank You for your guidance! (: